# Ошибки при создании билд файла

Tags: c#, build

**P.S: Windows 10 x64**

Пытаюсь скомпилировать программу из билдера но получаю ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[Исходники: Stub + Builder](https://mega.nz/#!86IF2IoL!-XsVAiAadcyxOr7w6stlKP7jJIG1b6H7kiOjX7EQsYc)

Вот код программы:

Stub:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[assembly: AssemblyTitle("[Title]")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("[Description]")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("[Company]")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("[Product]")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright © [Copyright] 2017")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: Guid("cd6d1750-58e0-4c29-94d4-6928876fa334")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "[TITLE_CONSOLE]";
            Console.WriteLine("[TEXT]");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Builder:

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BuildConsole
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateBuild(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
        }

        private void CreateBuild(string ConsoleTitleView, string ConsoleText)
        {
            var Result = Properties.Resources.Stub;
            Result = Result.Replace("[Title]", "Test");
            Result = Result.Replace("[Description]", "Test");
            Result = Result.Replace("[Company]", "Test");
            Result = Result.Replace("[Product]", "Test");
            Result = Result.Replace("[Copyright]", "Test");
            Result = Result.Replace("[TITLE_CONSOLE]", ConsoleTitleView);
            Result = Result.Replace("[TEXT]", ConsoleText);

            var providerOptions = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.5" } };

            CompilerResults results;
            using (var provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(providerOptions))
            {
                var Params = new CompilerParameters { OutputAssembly = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}/build.exe", GenerateExecutable = true, CompilerOptions = "/t:winexe" };

                Params.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");

                results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(Params, Result);
            }
            if (results.Errors.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Good");
            }
            foreach (CompilerError compilerError in results.Errors)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(compilerError.ErrorText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

А мне пишет что:

> Невозможно найти исполняемый файл компилятора csc.exe

Как можно решить эту проблему? ( желательно с **CodeDom** компилятором )

Comment: Ваш пример у меня выдаёт такую же ошибку. Ошибка пропадает, когда я ставлю `"CompilerVersion", "v3.5" }`. Win10 + VS2015 + VS2017. Проблема явно в путях: csc.exe от 4.5 не прописан в Path, подозреваю, что если добавить, то всё пройдёт на ура. Ну или взять машину без студии, поставить на неё только .Net Framework 4.5 и прописать в Path -- то же будет работать.

Comment: @AK, Спасибо, и в правду заработало =)

Comment: В Path ни одна версия не прописывается. Попробуйте использовать 4.0  или v4.0.30319 вместо 4.5 - потому что более новые версии фреймворка ставятся поверх 4.0

Comment: Ну или подключайте пакет Microsoft.CSharp и используйте более новый API...

Comment: @PavelMayorov, А можно подробнее про новый API ?

Comment: @Дмитрий [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш пример у меня выдаёт такую же ошибку.

Ошибка пропадает, когда я ставлю `"CompilerVersion", "v3.5" }`.

Win10 + VS2015 + VS2017.

Проблема явно в путях: csc.exe от 4.5 не прописан в Path, подозреваю, что если добавить, то всё пройдёт на ура.

Ну или взять машину без студии, поставить на неё только .Net Framework 4.5 и прописать в Path -- то же будет работать.

Любопытно: посмотрел Path на своей машине -- не вижу ничего ведущего в `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vX.X.XXX` или `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\vX.X.XXX` (там лежит [csc.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6660512/5752652))

Зато в Path есть `C:\Program Files\dotnet\` и похоже я отстал от жизни, надо будет почитать про Roslyn

Comment: А в версиях выше 4.0 `Net.Framework` имеется `csc.exe`  правильно ? Значит если он не установлен, то будет выбивать ошибку)

Comment: @Дмитрий Вот не знаю. В 2.0, 3.5, 4.0 вижу в C:\windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework, а потом уже c:\Program fies\dotnet\sdk1.03\Roslyn и выше находится. Вообще, насколько я знаю, этот компилятор обязан всегда поставляться с .Net Framework -- и даже если у тебя нет студии, можно в блокноте писать файлы и компилировать, я так ботов писал для википедии.

Comment: @AK версии 1-5 поставлялись вместе с фреймворком, компилятор для  C# 6 поставляется в пакете Microsoft Build Tools 2015 (отдельной версии фреймворка под него не было), для C# 7 уже нужно ставить Roslyn

Comment: @PavelMayorov Не хотите свой ответ дать? Мой на плюс тянет, на галку -- нет.

Comment: @AK но у меня под рукой нет чистого компьютера на котором я могу воспроизвести ситуацию :-)